# Unable to properly convert tf.keras model to quantized format for coral TPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, quantization, google-coral

I'am trying to convert a **tf.keras** model based on **mobilenetv2** with **transpose convolution** using latest **tf-nighlty**. Here is the conversion code

```
#saved_model_dir='/content/ksaved'  # tried from saved model also
#converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(reshape_model)
converter.experimental_new_converter=True
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8

converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen

tflite_quant_modell = converter.convert()
open("/content/model_quant.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_quant_modell)
```

The conversion was successful(in google colab); but it has **quantize and dequantize operators at the ends**(as seen using netron). All operators seems to be supported. **Representative data set** images are float32 in generator and the model has a 4 channel float32 input by default. It looks like we need a **UINT8 input and output** inside model for **coral TPU**. How can we properly carry out this conversion?

Ref:-

1. [Full integer quantization of weights and activations](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization#full_integer_quantization_of_weights_and_activations)
2. [How to quantize inputs and outputs of optimized tflite model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56856262/how-to-quantize-inputs-and-outputs-of-optimized-tflite-model)
3. [Coral Edge TPU Compiler cannot convert tflite model: Model not quantized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870564/coral-edge-tpu-compiler-cannot-convert-tflite-model-model-not-quantized)

I tried with 'tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file' instead of v2 version.I got error: "**Quantization not yet supported for op: TRANSPOSE_CONV**" while trying to quantize the model in latest tf 1.15 (using representative dataset) and "**Internal compiler error. Aborting!** " from coral tpu compiler using tf2.0 quantized tflite

Tflite model @ https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31368

[image]

It seems to work until the **last constitutional block** (1x7x7x160)
The compiler error(Aborting) does not give any information regarding the potential cause and all types of convolutional layers seems to be supported as per coral docs.

Coral doc: https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#quantization

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Namburger/4cc57ab3cbe4bf5abbc1d3e84536b75c) is a dummy model example of quantizing a keras model. Notice I'm using strict tf1.15 for the example, because tf2.0 deprecated:

```
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
```

with the `from_keras_model` api. I think the most confusing thing about this is that you can still call it but nothing happens. This means that model will still take in float inputs. I notice that you are using tf2.0, because `from_keras_model` is a tf2.0 api. Coral still suggest [using tf1.15](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#quantization) for converting model for now. I suggest downgrading tensorflow or maybe even just use this (while keeping tf2.0, it may or may not work):

```
tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file
```

More on it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/lite/TFLiteConverter).

Comment: I figured that out from link:https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36707. The problem was that it had transpose conv and is not supported by converter except recent tf-nigtly. Also, UINT8 input or output type seems to create a quantize and dequantize opeartors at  model end points(I used INT8 instead). While i have successfully converted to quantized tfllit in tf2.0, i'am not sure if i can convert to coral tpu format since it contains opeartors like ADD_V2, TRANSPOSE_CONV_V2 etc. In worst case i  will have to use resize bi-linear and train again i suppose..

Comment: I got error: "Quantization not yet supported for op: TRANSPOSE_CONV" while trying to quantize the model in latest tf 1.15 (using representative dataset) and "Internal compiler error. Aborting! " from coral tpu compiler using tf2.0 quantized tflite.

Answer (score 0):

I always make sure not to use the experimental converter:

```
converter.experimental_new_converter = False
```